# Can objects exist in spaces with different number of dimensions

Tags: spacetime-dimensions

Iam new to string theory and extra dimensions.

Some string theories suggest objects with many dimensions, I was just wondering if the space they exist in has the same number of dimensions - and in general is it thought that real objects could exist in dimensional space with at least 1 more or less dimensions?

Comment: What do you mean "real objects"? And why would a line not be able to live on a sphere? An object of dimensions d can live in any D-dimensional space as long as d is less than or equal to D obviously.  I do not understand what physics you are looking for or where string theory gets involved.

Comment: @PanosC. I suppose my question is Does the space containing the objects of N dimensions have (or have to have) the same number of dimensions? I imagine string theorists will have thought about this in great detail? The dimensions we observe interact completely seemlessly and I havent tripped over a 2-dimensional (+time) object lately so I think a 2-dimensional (macroscopic) object cannot exist in a 3 dimensional space, for example.

Comment: (If a 2D object can exist at all)